# Are there any controls to edit text with intellisense?

Tags: .net, wpf, intellisense, rule-engine

Are there any .net controls (hopefully WPF) to enter queries based on application rule engine (or language definition)? Something like SQL with intellisense or Jira advanced filter?

In other words i would like to allow a user to enter something like this into a text area

```
(type='apple' and color='green' and quantity>10) or (type='tomato' and color<>'red')
```

and the application would suggest a next valid token like intellisense.

Comment: yeah, me too.  additionally, an editor with these features implemented in javascript would be very compelling.

Comment: Atlassian did it in Jira with javascript. At least you can see how the did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it myself, but [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) uses [Actipro SyntaxEditor](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/WPF/SyntaxEditor/Default.aspx), which would at least be worth looking at.

Comment: Looks promising. Obviously it does A LOT more than i need but i wonder if it will do 90% of what i want or 100%. Will give it a try. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using the (standalone) rules engine from Workflow Foundation: http://footheory.com/blogs/bennie/archive/2007/05/10/alternative-applications-for-the-wf-rule-engine.aspx